# Grayscale image with colored border

Tags: css

I need to put a set of b/w images with colored borders on the page. I don't want to edit the images in Photoshop, since there may be some dynamically added ones later on; hence, I've used the corresponding `filter:grayscale(100%)`.

```
img.myImage {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   border: 6px solid #0090ff;
   width: 85%;
   margin: 0 auto;

   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

However, it affects the colored border, which also becomes grayish. Is there a "painless" workaround here?

Comment: Is there any reason for you not to put a wrapper around that image providing the border?

Comment: It depends what the border looks like. If it's like a rectangular frame that you know the size of, I can think of a possible hack... The best solution, however, is to use two images.

Comment: @MrLister, it's a round b/w image with light blue solid border. Actually, I've tried to put it inside a wrapper and it works, but I hoped to find a workaround with less code (both markup & CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `img` does not accept `:after`/`:before`, and since `filter` seems to apply on children elements, the only solution I can think of is the basic:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0090ff;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
   display: block;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg" alt="" />
</div>
```